# Why are some hats not awarded?

Tags: bug, hats

Even though I've done what was required, some hats are not being awarded. Why is this? (I'm not chasing hats (don't care really lol), but just noticed along the way that some are missing or have big delays).

Comment: What hats are you missing?  Hats are awarded every five minutes.

Comment: @iSeth I just checked and none seem to be missing (for sure) right now but the one for a question score of +5, I think might be missing (I have to double check). The other hats I got recently had big delays.

Comment: yeah, they have quite a delay, I tried going for the get r done hat, there must be a time requirment, also It seemed to take more than 5 edits for the editing hat, maybe review edits didn't count? An earlier experiment I did failed on meta...

Comment: They probably just had some server trouble.